# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError at android NDK

Tags: android-ndk

I am naive in android ndk right now . i tried steps given in this url: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_NDK.html
According to this i import sample of HELLO_JNI in my eclipse from android ndkr_10 and when i ran it throws error in logcat given below

08-17 18:12:01.472: E/AndroidRuntime(1269): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load hello-jni from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.hellojni-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.hellojni-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null

can somebody help me sort this problem 
where i miss?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your error mean that no `hello-jni` lib was found. The tutorial you follow says that you should have `myjni` lib.

After compiling your projet to an apk you can run the command line `unzip -l you_apk_file`. In the list of file you should see your `.so` file.

Comment: Thank u for ur sugesstion but there is so many .so file in every folder  which one i should use
well i got the solution it were my mistake i forget to add plugin on eclipse for ndk as plugin now its working very fine